# How to access event data for LHCb calorimeters?

Tags: physics

I want to do a project using machine learning on the calorimeter event data of the LHCb. How can I access this data? Is it very difficult to navigate your way through the source code on your own?

Answer (score 0):

As far as gaining access to the lhcb calorimeter database, I am not sure if that is publicly available.

However, I can tell you that once you have this dataset, you will need to use some data science tools to get the machine learning data out of it. Hadoop is a common stack for big data, but how to set up and use Hadoop is WAY outside the scope of this post.

http://hadoop.apache.org/